# Prove $(g^TBg)(g^TB^{-1}g)\ge(g^Tg)^2$ if $B$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm trying to prove this inequality
$$(g^TBg)(g^TB^{-1}g)\ge(g^Tg)^2,$$
when $B$ is a positive definite matrix. I got a hint that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be used.

I tried this way. Define $a=B^Tg$ and $b=B^{-1}g$ then the original inequality becomes
$$(a^Tg)(g^Tb)\ge(g^Tg)^2,$$
when $a^Tb=g^Tg$ and $B$ is positive definite. I found it looks like the form of Cauchy inequality but not exactly, and I have no clue about how to use the positive definiteness of $B$. Any hint help me continue ?

Update: I guess I made a mistake about the definition of $a$. A transpose is required.

Comment: The positive definitess is so because you assume $B^{-1}$ exists and so has to be P.D.

Comment: @ElBazzi Thanks. Yes, we can conclude $B^{-1}$ exists and is also positive definite. But I still don't know how to apply Cauchy inequality here.

Comment: I suppose $B$ is symmetric?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes. Common definition of positive definite matrix requires symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $B$ is positive definite, it has an inverse $B^{-1}$ square root $B^{1/2}$. (Can be obtained, for example, by considering the eigendecomposition of $B$.) Note that $B^{1/2}$ is also positive definite with inverse $B^{-1/2}$.

I will prove the more general statement $(g^\top h)^2 \le (g^\top B g)(h^\top B^{-1} h)$, from which your inequality can be derived by setting $h=g$. Note that this inequality is a special case of [dual norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Mathematical_Optimization) in the case of [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

\begin{align}
(g^\top B g)(h^\top B^{-1} h)
&= \|B^{1/2} g\|^2 \|B^{-1/2} h\|^2\\
&\ge ((B^{1/2} g)^\top (B^{-1/2} h))^2 & \text{Cauchy-Schwarz}\\
&= (g^\top h)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I guess I got your idea. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

For a general inner product the Cauchy inequality states that

$$\forall a,b,\, \langle a,b\rangle^2\leq \langle a,a\rangle\langle b,b\rangle$$

Now because $B$ is definite positive $\langle a,b\rangle=a^TBb$ defines an inner product and applying the Cauchy inequality to $a=g$ and $b=B^{-1}g$ one gets using that $B^{-1}$ is symmetric (in fact definite positive)

$$\left(g^TBB^{-1}g\right)^2\leq \left(g^TBg\right)\left( g^TB^{-1}BB^{-1}g\right)$$

And this is the desired inequality.

We have setting $a=g$ and $b=B^{-1}h$ the more general inequality

$$\left(g^Th\right)^2\leq \left(g^TBg\right)\left(h^TB^{-1}h\right)$$

Comment: Oh, This is clever !

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cauchy inequality is very powerful

Answer (score 2):

Using the spectral theorem, we may write $B=P^TDP$, where $P$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal with all entries are positive. Let $h=Pg$. Then the problem is equivalent to:

$$(h^TDh)\cdot(h^TD^{-1}h)\geq (h^Th)^2$$

If $h=\sum_{i=1}^nc_ie_i$ and $D=(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^n$, then the LHS is

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot{c_i}^2\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\cdot{c_i}^2\right)$$

and the RHS is

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{c_i}^2\right)^2$$

Can you now see this as a special case of [Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Counting_measure)?

Comment: I guess your  idea is similar to @angryavian but gives a more detailed elaboration. Thanks !

Comment: When you say "special case of Hölder's inequality," are you referring to Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: No, I mean $p=q=2$ and a choice of $x_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}\cdot c_i$, $y_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}\cdot c_i$.

Comment: Well, one can see that as Cauchy-Schwarz with $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$. Hölder's came to my mind first, but I guess you're right.

Comment: Very clever!+1)